# how to add more images to existing custom object detection model

Tags: tensorflow

I developed object detection model through custom images. That model is working fine but now I want add more images to the model.

How to add more images to existing custom object detection model?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the model to be able to recognize more objects, you need to retrain it with a dataset containing labeled images of the new objets to detect.

Comment: Can you explain how to retrain the object detection model

Comment: You need to prepare your image dataset and feed it to your model just like you did for the first training. So your new data should have the same dimension. You can find a tutorial for tensorflow models here : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

Comment: Thank you,This tutorial is image classifier but i trained object detection model, i think both are different